# How do I define on which subplot(s) to show contour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I've created subplots showing xarray features over an ocean-coastline area whereupon I want to add a contour to show where sealevel is.

Started with:

`world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))`

`fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=[18,15],nrows=2,ncols=2)`

Then added my "backgrounds" specified for each subplots as examples show below (together with some x- and y-limitations and additional things to plot on top):

`world.plot(ax=axes[0][0], color = 'darkgrey', edgecolors ='black')`
`ds.ROSE.plot(ax=axes[0][1], cmap='Blues_r', vmin=-6000, vmax=0)`

I've managed to code the contour itself: `cs = plt.contour(ds.longitude, ds.latitude, ds.ROSE, levels=0, colors='black', linewidths=0.5)` but just cannot find out how to make it show up anywhere but on the last subplot. I've moved the contour code block around within the cell and tried to somehow imply the same commands as for the backgrounds (`ax=axes[0][1]` etc.) but all I get is contours on subplot `[1][1]` or nowhere.

How do I designate the plt.contour to show up on one particular subplot? I want the contour on all the three xarray subplots.

Comment: Use `plt.sca(my_desired_ax)` to 'set current axes' to your desired axes before you use `plt.countour`?

Comment: Use the axes you want to plot on instead of `plt` e.g. `ax[0][0].contour(...)`

Comment: Yeeey solved it with both suggested methods, Thanx!